# Why does my build fail when I update my Git repo for Vercel deployment?

Tags: github, vercel

I have a minor problem- I deployed an application on Vercel a week ago and everything was working fine until this week when I pushed some changes on my git repo, could any one help me understand why this is not working? This is the response I get from Vercel:

```
20:43:49.248    Installing build runtime...
20:43:49.657    Build runtime installed: 409.181ms
20:43:50.447    Installing dependencies...
20:44:15.136    > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /vercel/workpath0/imogen_portfolio/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
20:44:15.136    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
20:44:15.213    [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m
20:44:15.213    [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: [0m
20:44:15.213    [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
20:44:15.213    [96m>[94m https://www.patreon.com/zloirock [0m
20:44:15.213    [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m
20:44:15.239    > core-js@3.7.0 postinstall /vercel/workpath0/imogen_portfolio/node_modules/core-js
20:44:15.239    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
20:44:15.306    > core-js-pure@3.7.0 postinstall /vercel/workpath0/imogen_portfolio/node_modules/core-js-pure
20:44:15.306    > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
20:44:15.397    > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /vercel/workpath0/imogen_portfolio/node_modules/ejs
20:44:15.397    > node ./postinstall.js
20:44:15.458    Thank you for installing [35mEJS[0m: built with the [32mJake[0m JavaScript build tool ([32mhttps://jakejs.com/[0m)
20:44:17.268    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
20:44:17.268    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20:44:17.274    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
20:44:17.274    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20:44:17.282    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.2.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
20:44:17.282    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.2.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20:44:17.290    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
20:44:17.290    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
20:44:17.295    added 2003 packages from 827 contributors in 26.418s
20:44:18.440    124 packages are looking for funding
20:44:18.440      run `npm fund` for details
20:44:18.654    Running "npm run build"
20:44:18.857    > imogen_portfolio@0.1.0 build /vercel/workpath0/imogen_portfolio
20:44:18.857    > react-scripts build
20:44:20.138    Creating an optimized production build...
20:44:21.211    Failed to compile.
20:44:21.212    ./src/index.js
20:44:21.212    Cannot find file './components/theme' in './src'.
20:44:21.231    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
20:44:21.231    npm ERR! errno 1
20:44:21.233    npm ERR! imogen_portfolio@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
20:44:21.234    npm ERR! Exit status 1
20:44:21.234    npm ERR! 
20:44:21.234    npm ERR! Failed at the imogen_portfolio@0.1.0 build script.
20:44:21.234    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
20:44:21.243    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
20:44:21.243    npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2020-11-26T19_44_21_234Z-debug.log
20:44:21.248    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
20:44:23.410    Done with "package.json"
```

Comment: Assuming you set up everything correctly, this looks like you're missing the `theme` file in ./components